# Как получить массив групп товаров при обработке файла excel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xls, xlsx

Подскажите как можно получить массив сгруппированных товаров из файла excel.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я обрабатываю файл, но разбиения на группы нет, выдает просто по порядку все строки.

```
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("bulat_price.xlsx");
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$worksheet->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, как получить уровень вложенности или многоуровневую группировку строк.
Использовал PHPExcel т.к. подходит для старых версий PHP.
PhpSpreadsheet идет от версии PHP 5.6.

```
$spreadsheet = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file); // Загружаем файл
$objWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0); // Выбираем первый лист

$i = 0;
$arrLevel = [];

foreach ($worksheet->getRowDimensions() as $rowDimension) {
    $i++;
    $arrLevel[$i]['level'] = $rowDimension->getOutlineLevel(); // Определяем уровень вложенности
}
$highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'

foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {    
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true);

    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $arrLevel[$row->getRowIndex()]["excel"][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getValue(); // Объединяем глубину вложенности и данные из столбцов и строк
    }
}

var_dump($arrLevel);
```

Получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]